# Emberjs Service is undefined after loading

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to inject 'eventBus' service into my component but after injection service is undefined. I am using ember 2 and I was following this tutorial (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/applications/services/) but it doesn't work for me.

services/event-bus.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend(Ember.Evented, {
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
  },
  publish: function() {
    return this.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  subscribe: function() {
    this.on.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  unsubscribe: function() {
    this.off.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

components/rooms-list.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const RoomList = Ember.Component.extend({
  eventBus: Ember.inject.service(),
  didReceiveAttrs () {
    this.set('currentRoomId', this.get('params')[1].id);
  },
  model: Ember.computed('params.[]', function(){
    return this.get('params')[0];
  }),
  actions: {
    onRoomClicked(roomId) {
      this.get('eventBus').publish(); //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined
      this.set('currentRoomId', roomId);
    },
    deleteRoom(room) {
      console.log('delete room', room);
    }
  }
});

RoomList.reopenClass({
  positionalParams: 'params'
});

export default RoomList;
```

inside `onRoomClicked` method `this.eventBus` is

[this.eventBus object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lpBI.png)

Comment: Can you try: `eventBus: Ember.inject.service('event-bus'),`

Comment: I did and the final result was the same. It strange for me because it looks like simple code which should work but it doesn't...

Comment: Did you try [initialize](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/applications/initializers/) the service instead of ad-hoc injection?

Comment: I did check it one more time and solution ykaragol does work. so thank you