# Ember service is undefined after being injected into a component and used in a computed property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've made a relatively straight-forward Ember service and am trying to inject it into a component via the [Ember Docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/applications/services/) and [this tutorial](https://www.emberscreencasts.com/posts/82-introduction-to-services). However after injecting the service and calling one of its functions via a computed property, I get the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.get('businessValidator').validate')
```

I've tried using the debugger to log out this.get('businessValidator') and it returns undefined, as does using console.log. I've tried initializing the component both by name (as below) and implicitly (without the name, as it should work per the Ember docs and [unmarked solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755816/emberjs-service-is-undefined-after-loading)). The model passed to the component is the business the businessValidation service needs to validate. I've done plenty of unit testing on the service itself.

**/components/production-checker.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  businessValidator: Ember.inject.service('business-validator'),
  doesBusinessValidate: Ember.computed('model', function() {
     if (this.get('businessValidator').validate(this.get('model'))) {
      return "Ready for business!";
     } else {
       return "Production is halted!";
     }
  })
});
```

**services/business-validator.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
  },
  validate(business) {
    let validMarkets = this.validateTargetMarkets(business);
    let validChosenProduct = this.validateChosenProduct(business);
    let validSuppliers = this.validateRequiredSuppliers(business);
    let validPrice = this.validatePrice(business);
    let validWorkers = this.validateWorkers(business);
    let validLocations = this.validateLocations(business);
    if (validMarkets && validChosenProduct && validSuppliers && validPrice && validWorkers && validLocations) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  validateTargetMarkets(business) {
    if (business.get("targetMarkets") && business.get('targetMarkets').get('length') > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  validateChosenProduct(business) {
    if (business.get("chosenProduct")) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  validateRequiredSuppliers(business) {
    let result = false;
    if (business.get("chosenProduct") && business.get("chosenProduct").get("requiredResources") && business.get("chosenProduct").get("requiredResources").length > 0) {
      result = business.get("chosenProduct").get("requiredResources").every(function(item) {
        if (item.get('chosenSupplier')) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    }

    if (result) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  validatePrice(business) {
    if (business.get('chosenProduct') && business.get('chosenProduct').get('price') && business.get('chosenProduct').get('price') > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  validateWorkers(business) {
    if (business.get('workers') && business.get('workers').get('length') > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  validateLocations(business) {
    if (business.get('locations') && business.get('locations').get('length') > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

});
```

Ember version:

```
Ember      : 2.5.1
Ember Data : 2.5.2
jQuery     : 2.2.3
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't call methods with `this.get('validateTargetMarkets')(business)`, just say `this.validateTargetMarkets(business)`. Although this might not be your core problem. Also, it's always better to say `return b` than `if (b) return true; else return false;`.

Comment: Would the following work: `this.get('businessValidator.validate')(this.get('model');`?

Comment: What version of ember are you using ?

Comment: Added the Ember version to the post above. Regarding calling methods, I'm happy to call them without .get(function), but I was under the impression that I should  in case the service is uninitialized. Because it's an internal function call, I don't have to worry about that? Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually your code should work. Checkout [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/457abe418872edc4a9ca36ffed6132d4?openFiles=services.business-validator.js%2Ctemplates.components.production-checker.hbs).

So your problem is not related to the code you posted.

Maybe you don't use the latest ember version?

Also if you show us your code or a not working twiddle we can tell you more, but for this question everything is working.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Using Ember twiddle showed that this pattern should work. I fired up my laptop and Ember server to start testing things and TADA -- my broken code from last night was suddenly working just fine. Thought it might have been a result of not restarting the Ember server after creating the service or component, but tests this morning doing that worked just fine. I'm left wondering if for some reason my file system didn't acknowledge the service file once created, but it looks like it will remain a Ghost Error mystery. For future people: verify a test-case with Ember-Twiddle!

Comment: Had the same issue. Restarting "ember server" fixed it - without any additional action.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the issue here but, I spent some time on this when developing an addon. My service was always undefined, even when using the this.get('service_name') in my comp. This is the way to access them because properties are lazyloaded(https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/applications/services/).

I found out that the service must exist in the app folder as well, not only in the addon/service folder, and then point to the addons service.

Using the `ember generate service service_name` creates all the needed files...